# Is header allowed in basketball?

Tags: rules, basketball, nba

I know kicking ball in NBA is not allowed, how about header? is header like football allowed in basketball?

Comment: Are you talking about an intentional header or just one that bounces off your head by accident?  I'm pretty sure you're looking for intentional, but I just wanna make sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kicking the ball is covered in Rule 10 Section IV of the [NBA Rules](http://www.nba.com/media/dleague/1314-nba-rule-book.pdf).  That includes also "striking the ball with his fist", ie, punching the ball, by the way.

It does not cover heading the ball, nor are there any other places in the rules that I could find that referred to intentionally hitting the ball with your head (or unintentionally doing so).  I can't imagine it would give a player a significant advantage to do so - basketballs are *hard*, and quite hard to redirect with your head.  Even a 7' tall player still has 2 feet or so (after jumping) to move the ball, plus the height of the ball over the rim, plus the direction - it's unlikely to go in, and much easier to use the hands.

Marc Gasol did this in [a game in the 2014-2015 season](http://sports.yahoo.com/blogs/nba-ball-dont-lie/grizzlies--marc-gasol-tries-soccer-style-header-after-getting-fouled-030652402.html), though it didn't accomplish anything other than probably giving him a bit of a headache; it was also after a foul, so it wasn't definitively a proof that it's allowed.